# Go back to previous fragment gives empty container

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am developing a android app with a menu bar, I have the mainactivity, this has a menu bar and a fragment navigation inside the container. When the app launches it auto sets a fragment in the main_container

```
<FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

The navigation goes to:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/spliFragment">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/spliFragment"
    android:name="com.example.tutorme.ui.SearchResultsFragment"
    android:label="SearchResultsFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/search_results_fragment">
</fragment>
```

Now I want to replace the fragment in the main_container if I press a item in the menu, I do this in the onNavigationItemSelected:

```
 else if (id == R.id.xx){
        Fragment newFrag = new xxFrag();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, newFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

This all works however when I press the back button, It just goes back but not to fragment in the container I replaced. It goes back to a empty container. 
How would I be able to solve this ?

Comment: You are using navigation graph, why don't add the action inside your fragment ?

Comment: That part of the code wasn't made by me so I would rather not change that but  if I don't find a solution I will just erase the navigation

Comment: I would suggest you to add action inside your navigation graph. It simple.